# pyqt : Display All values present in QListWidget as selected to user

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have searched a lot but I am unable to find a solution for doing this.

I have a QListWidget which will populate a list of values. I need to implement a "select all" as default behaviour in the list.

I have already used MultiSelection and that works well, but the need is to avoid clicking on each item, in case the user wants to do the update on all items listed.

Can someone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: Could you explain me better, what behavior do you expect? Do you want that if you press a button, select all the items?

Comment: I have 2 comboboxes, when I have values selected in both of them, a function loads the QListWidget with values. But for a specific value in 1 of the comboboxes, e.g. 'All_Routes', I would like to have the QListWidget have values but all as already selected.

Comment: From what I understand you want one of the items in a combobox to be "select everything" and then you must auto-select all the items in the QListWidget, and if after selecting everything change the combobox item you must select that same combobox item? Are the combobox items the same as the QListWidget?

Comment: You understood correctly.
And no, the combobox items are not the same as QListWidget items. As I said, I have a function which is called after the selection of both the combobox items and then it loads the QListWidget with the output of the function as list.

Comment: From what you say I understand you want the QListWidget to have a "selectAll()" function, am I right? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to implement a function that selects all items, the solution is to iterate using the `setSelected()` method of `QListWidget` as shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class ListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QListWidget.MultiSelection)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def selectAll(self):
        for i in range(self.count()):
            it = self.item(i)
            if it is not None:
                it.setSelected(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def clearSelection(self):
        for i in range(self.count()):
            it = self.item(i)
            if it is not None:
                it.setSelected(False)


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        button_sel = QtGui.QPushButton("Select All")
        button_unsel = QtGui.QPushButton("Clear Selection")

        self.list_widget = ListWidget()

        for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            it = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(letter)
            self.list_widget.addItem(it)

        button_sel.clicked.connect(self.list_widget.selectAll)
        button_unsel.clicked.connect(self.list_widget.clearSelection)

        lay.addWidget(button_sel)
        lay.addWidget(button_unsel)
        lay.addWidget(self.list_widget)     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want but without the button click event.

Comment: @Shoikat The button is something optional, you can make the selection with: `self.list_widget.selectAll()`

Comment: @Shoikat If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection`

> When the user selects an item in the usual way, the selection is cleared and the new item selected. However, if the user presses the Ctrl key when clicking on an item, the clicked item gets toggled and all other items are left untouched. If the user presses the Shift key while clicking on an item, all items between the current item and the clicked item are selected or unselected, depending on the state of the clicked item. Multiple items can be selected by dragging the mouse over them.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    for i in range(12):
        w.addItem('Item {}'.format(i))

    w.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)  

    #w.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)  

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hello,

I do not want the user to select the item. I want to list all the items in the QListWidget as already selected.